# google V8 build error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ws2_32.lib'

Tags: build, visual-studio-2012, linker, v8

I'm trying to build google's V8 JavaScript Engine with MS Visual Studio 2012 on a 64bit system, but it always outputs the error

```
 LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ws2_32.lib'
```

I have done everything according to https://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/BuildingWithGYP. I have used the python way instead of cygwin to generate the project files.

How do i set up my linker that it finds the `ws2_32.lib`?

**//EDIT** For some reason GYP made project files for vs2010 and not vs2012 so I had to update them. Now it works. (weird, I tried this before and it didn't work)

Comment: Mhm. I have built a 64bit v8 with Visual Studio 2012 on 64bit Windows using GYP myself. I know this does not really answer your question, but just to confirm it's doable. I don't recall having any lib linking issues. Have you done a checkout of the "third_party\cygwin"? You still need it even with GYP/Python build.

Comment: yes I have a checkout of third_party\cygwin. And the creation of the project files works fine, but visual studio outputs this linking error when I try to build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GYP created VS2010 project files so I had to update them to VS2012.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered several problems including yours before I managed to build and link against V8 on windows 7 64bit - ( i built for 32bit ).

1. ensure that you have added a "third_party" folder to the V8 checkout and within it added cygwin and python_26 from the google uri in the docs.  ( greping V8 files for "third_party" indicates the precise file structure ).
2. now run the gyp tool.  ( Exactly the same feedback as when third_party is missing just takes a bit longer and actually works instead of generating junk solution file ).
3. load all.sln and it should all build debug and release.  I am using vs2012 and DIDNT upgrade the project from vs2010 which may matter.

Finally when it comes to linking against v8_base.ia32.lib and v8_snapshot.lib ( or 64bit versions ) - I needed to link "Ws2_32.lib" and "winmm.lib" due to unresolved externals in the V8 lib.

For some reason V8 requires access to win32 sockets api and multimedia timers.  Would be nice to have a stripped down option with no hidden platform api wrappers.